# Selecting port for sending data on TCP layer

Tags: c, tcp, port

I written a C program for sending and receiving a data on the TCP layer. I have created a socket for sending and receiving a data over a specific IP address.
 Question : How to identify the free IP address and port number on the laptop ?? So that I can use it for communication.
I am using windows 7 operating system.

Comment: I think you can use `netstat` to see what ports are currently being used, and pick a different port.

Comment: I tried ipconfig and it will display only ip address.

Comment: @Barmar : For the udp port ??

Comment: What UDP port? You said you're using TCP, not UDP.

Comment: just for knowledge : for knowing the udp port number : netstat -a

Comment: It shows a list of port number : what is the name if the port is free (example : close wait, time wait, established , listening ) ??

Comment: @user2984410, what are you really asking?  What's the laptop in this scenario, the server or the client?  Are you looking for a server port that clients can connect to or are you trying (for some unknown reason) to predetermine what port the clients use?

Comment: `LISTENING` is ports that other servers are using. The rest are usually ephemeral ports used by clients.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the name if the port is free (example : close wait, time wait,
>   established , listening ) ??

`LISTENING` is ports that other servers are using. The rest are usually ephemeral ports used by clients. – Barmar